# Kafka does not consume messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have update my kafka from version 0.10.2.0 to versión 2.1.0 and now kafka is not able to consume messages. I am using spring boot and here is my configuration:

```java
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServers);
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, topic + "kafka2");
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 3000000);
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, 2000000000);
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "900000");
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "905000");
configProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "35000");
```

I have change the group id, to avoid problems with the old group id. 
My current version of spring is 2.1.2.RELEASE. And in my application I can see how my client is constantly reconnecting

Any idea of the problem?

Comment: There is no 0.1.0. What boot version? Turn on DEBUG logging to see if it helps see what is wrong.

Comment: sorry, my client was 0.10.2.0, and my current version of spring is 2.1.2.RELEASE. And in my application I can see how my client is constantly reconnecting

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific when talking about "spring versions". There are many spring projects with different versions.

I presume you mean Spring Boot is 2.1.2 (the current 2.1.x version is 2.1.6, by the way).

Spring Boot 2.1.6 uses Spring for Apache Kafka 2.2.7 which, in turn, uses `kafka-clients` 2.0.1.

I would not expect any problems using a 2.0.x kafka-clients with a 2.1.0 broker, but you could try overriding the kafka clients versions to 2.1.0, as [described in the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#deps-for-21x).

Again, I suggest enabling DEBUG logging for `apache.kafka` to see if it provides you with more information.